# PyQt:How do I get the current tablewidget in a tabs widget?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a tab widget with tablewidgets in each one, containing cells with links.I know how to get the current text from a tablewidget and open it in a browser,which is what i want to do.

```
selection=str(self.tableWidget_1.currentItem().text()).encode('utf8')
webbrowser.open(selection,new=2)
```

My problem is that I don't know how to get the current tablewidget instead of predetermined like above.Any ideas?Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`QTabWidget.currentWidget`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtabwidget.html#currentIndex).